# QGIS: project hangs when using atlas variable in a rule-based symbology

Tags: qgis

I have an issue when using the variable @atlas_pagename in a rule-based symbology.

Here is the context:  my project has 3 layers:

1. a feature layer with all the grid cells covering the territory (geopackage layer). It is a MGRS 1x1 km grid with 23000 features, each of them has a unique grid identifier (MGRS) and I have created
   an attribute index on this column
2. one sqlite table (table spec_mgrs) with 2 columns : MGRS grid code (column mgrs01) and species name (column species)
3. one sqlite table containing all the species I want to map (table species)

I have created a simple layout and activated the atlas feature.  The coverage layer is the table called species (list of species); the page name is set to the column containing the species name

The issue comes when I try to apply a rule-based symbology on the grid layer.  The idea is to draw only the grid cells where the current species (driven by atlas) has been recorded (this information is found in table spec_mgrs)
Here is the expression I try to use :

`array_contains(aggregate('spec_mgrs','array_agg',"mgrs01", "species"=@atlas_pagename),"MGRS")`

This expression hangs the project and never display anything.

If I replace @atlas_pagename in the expression by a hard coded species name, everything is running fast and fine.  Example:

`array_contains(aggregate('spec_mgrs','array_agg',"mgrs01", "species"='Ammobates punctatus'),"MGRS")`
is ok

I don't see where is the problem...

Edit : I use QGis 3.16.14 on Windows 10

Comment: See here: does that help? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/425977/88814

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Unfortunately, that doesn't help me