# Fieldname as variable in with_variable returns value not the field

Tags: qgis, expression, geometry-generator

I want to use a field name as a variable inside the geometry generator, but it replaces the field name with the current value of the feature instead of taking the field name as the variable.

Expression how I want it:

```
with_variable('field',Pop_20,
    array_min(aggregate(layer:='MainStatistik',aggregate:='array_agg',expression:=@field))
    array_max(aggregate(layer:='MainStatistik',aggregate:='array_agg',expression:=@field))
)

Output:
   4045
   4045
```

Because it calls the value of the Pop_20 field and does not take the name of the field it gives out just the value of that specific feature and not the desired min and max of the whole field.
If I put the field name directly into the *aggregate* function it works as desired.

Expression that works:

```
array_min(aggregate(layer:='MainStatistik',aggregate:='array_agg',expression:="Pop_20"))
array_max(aggregate(layer:='MainStatistik',aggregate:='array_agg',expression:="Pop_20"))

Output:
    2093
    27755
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the definition of the variable, set the variable's value in single quotes `'` and call the variable with `eval()` function:

```
with_variable(
    'field',
    'Pop_20',
    array_min(
        aggregate(
            layer:='MainStatistik',
            aggregate:='array_agg',
            expression:=eval(@field)
         )
     )
)
```

Explanation: if you define the variable's value without quotes or with double quotes `"` (both versions are basically the same), you call the actual **value** (content) of the current feature's `Pop_20` field. But you define the variable not to call the **value**, but the **name** of the field: so the varible must be a string: thus single quotes.

When you call the variable, you must evaluate it using `eval()`, see [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#eval):

> Evaluates an expression which is passed in a string. Useful to expand
> dynamic parameters passed as context variables or fields.